# Iteração de array de objetos com o map retorna undefined

Tags: javascript

Estou consumindo a API do GitHub e estou percorrendo os repositórios de um determinado usuário, mas ao tentar acessar as propriedades ele está retornando `undefined`.

Como podem ver na imagem, o meu `result` está retornando todos os objetos dos repositórios, porém ao tentar percorrê-los usando o `rep` que está sendo passado como parâmetro ele retorna apenas o primeiro repositório, mas a ideia seria retornar todos os repositórios.

Minha função que percorre os repositórios usando o `map()`:

```
  getRepos = type => {
    return e => {
      axios
        .get(`https://api.github.com/users/Giovanni001/${type}`)
        .then(result => {
          console.log("RESULT", result);
          this.setState({
            [type]: result.data.map(rep => {
            console.log("REP", rep);
              return {
                name: rep.data.name,
                link: rep.data.html_url
              };
            })
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("ERRO: ", err);
          return <h1>Ops, deu algo errado !</h1>;
        });
      };
    };
```

[image: meu parametro <code>rep</code> trazendo apenas um repositório]

[image: MEU PARAMETRO <code>result</code> que está percorrendo os repositórios trazendo todos os repositórios]

[image: o erro undefined que está retornando ao tentar acessar a propriedade <code>name</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está muito claro aí Jovem, **Não pode ler a propriedade *`name`* de *`indefinido`***, pq:

> No seu **map()** vc já está pegando os dados de **data**

```
[type]: result.data.map(rep => { ...
```

E aí quando faz no **return**:

```
name: rep.data.name,     <= erro de acesso de propriedade
link: rep.data.html_url  <= erro de acesso de propriedade
```

> Dá o erro pq **rep** já possui os dados de **result** e **data**, para corrigir o erro é só acessar diretamente a propriedade no **rep**:

```
name: rep.name,     <= acesso da propriedade nome
link: rep.html_url  <= acesso da propriedade html-url
```

Comment: Olá, eu tinha feito uma requisição em outra função e estava pegando os dados usando o data, eu estava tao fixado nisso q nao me dei conta de q o data já estava sendo passado no loop, Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Isso acontece muito durante o desenvolvimento man :)